# Trying to create a function where you merge rows in a column in the eventual excel spreadsheet

Tags: r, function, openxlsx

I'm trying to create a basic function to do some repeating tasks in some excel/CSV analysis, using the OpenXLSX package, just to automate some analysis, and I'm just doing some formatting to make it more "readable"

```
mergingRows<-function(dataframe,column,number,workbook,worksheet){
   terms<-unique(dataframe$column)
     for(k in c(1:length(terms))){
      toMerge<-which(dataframe$column==terms[k])
      toMerge<-toMerge+number
      mergeCells(workbook,worksheet,cols=1,rows = toMerge)
     }
  }
```

I might call the function like this:

```
mergingRows(tempCurrentPOs,Requisitioner,4+nrow(tempCurrentPOSubTotals),CurrentOpenPOBook,groupName)
```

When I actually run the function, I tend to get a lot of warnings like these

```
Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'column'.
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'column'.
3: In min(rows) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(rows) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'column'.
```

etc.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: While we don't have data to test, Is `Requisitioner` the name of a variable that stores the name of a column, or is it the name of a column in the data? If the latter, you are trying to do [non-standard evaluation (NSE)](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), which your function is not set to do. Further, if `column` (inside the function) is assumed to be `character`, then replace `$column` with `[[column]]`.

Comment: Requisitioner is ideally the name of the column in the dataset.  Thank you for the suggestions!  I'll do more research then.

Comment: Try replacing `Requisitioner` with `"Requisitioner"` and `$column` with `[[column]]`, and see if that behaves any better.

Comment: That worked out perfectly.  Thank you so much.